# Measures of printed map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, printing

I created a simple map with a point and a buffer (3 km) in QGIS2.18 (and also 3.4) with CRS WGS84 UTM33.

With QGIS Composer I created the layout adding the scalebars (for 500 m and 3 km) and printed a map in scale 1:50000.

After exporting the map as PDF and printed it, I checked the distance on the paper map  and I noticed that these are not so perfect: the measures of scalebars are ok (eg: 1 cm in the scale bar is equal to 1 cm on the ruler) but width and height of grids are little bit lower.

I also noticed that exporting the map as image (png) I have errors in scalebar (only in the 3 km one), buffer and grids, instead exporting in PDF, errors are visible only on the grids.

Pictures of measure are availabe at this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yucbe09anoycv5e/AACatT69ixjIIj-AUQ1wdjaUa?dl=0).

Did I wrong something in print setting or in the map?

Comment: What's the EPSG code of the projection you're using?

Comment: EPSG : 32633, the unit is meter

Comment: The scope of EPSG:32633 is described on epsg.io as "Scope: Large and medium scale topographic mapping and engineering survey." Large vs small scale is somewhat subjective, but 1:50000 is probably in the medium to small scale range. Try using a CRS intended for medium to small scale mapping in your areas of interest. For example, EPSG:3416 promises 1.0m accuracy within the scope of Austria.

Comment: Usually in Italy the main CRS used are EPGS 32632, 32633, 3003 and 3004, all have "Large and medium scale topographic mapping and engineering survey" as scope. I tried with the CRS 3416 and another suggested in epsg.io typing "Italy" in the search form (I chose 7794 with scope: "Small scale topographic mapping and GIS for whole country") but the resuts are the same as EPSG 32633